# PowerBi - This data source cannot be accessed by data gateway

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I tried to publish my report on dashboard. and I get this error

```
This data source cannot be accessed by data gateway.
```

I used direct query from my sql server. I downloaded and installed on-premise data gateway.

When I go to Manage Gateway in Power BI service. It says you do not have any gateways.

Not really sure as to what to do.

Please someone guide me.

[image: This is the error that I get]

Answer (score 2):

When using Direct Query, you must configure the gateway's data sources under manage gateways

If you cannot see any gateways under manage gateways, then one of four scenarios has occurred.

1. You have not finished the install process for the On-Premise Data Gateway
2. You have not Signed into the OpDG ( locally where it was installed )
3. You used a different accounts when publishing the report and signing in to the OpDG
4. ( Very outlandish ) You installed the OpDG somewhere that it just cannot see an outside network. Perhaps a bad region? This can be changed in the local config page for the OpDG

To Fix this:

1. Re-Install the OpDG
2. Sign-in locally to the OpDG using the same account you published with
3. *Try* changing the region. I don't think it's this.

Next:

Under manage gateways, once you can see the gateway, you need to add a source. The Source must Suit two conditions. It must have the FQDN of the server.database **AND** it must be the *exact* same connection string used in the local PBIx File you published.

Ex. If you Direct-Queried to *MyDomain.ServerOne.ProductionDatabase*, but in PowerBI Desktop, you just said Localhost:ProdData, you'll have an issue. Make sure both the PBIx and the DataSource under your gateway online both have the FQDN.

Then You should be able to assign a gateway under the dataset settings ( Dataset -> Schedule refresh -> Choose Data Gateway )

Good Luck!